# Destroying iPad Mini 1

Tags: ipad, damage

I would like to know how long an iPad Mini would need to stay in water in a way that it is never ever usable again. I know this is a bit unusual, but I'd really like to get rid of the old device and I'm also curious what it would take to destroy the device. I've already had my device a day ago for about 22 hours in the water, but I can still use the device without any major problems. In fact, this post was written on it.

So would anyone know how long it would take to completely destroy the device?

Comment: How about a hammer?  It worked really well for [Hillary Clinton](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-hillary-clinton-aide-destroyed-phones-2016-9)

Comment: Get rid of:  You can reset it to factory settings so all data has been reset, and let Apple recycle it.   https://www.apple.com/recycling/nationalservices/

Comment: Are you concerned about the data on the iPad being recovered? While you of course are free to do what you like with your electronics, this isn't particularly environmentally responsible. First gen iPad Minis are still usable enough, I imagine Apple or similar would buy it.

Comment: I agree, don't kill it. Reset the iPad (wiping your data) and then give it away to some less fortunate kid. No reason to destroy a working iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Proven method is to use a hammer as practiced by [Hillary Clinton](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-hillary-clinton-aide-destroyed-phones-2016-9).

Not even FBI could crack those devices.

Leaving it in water will not destroy the memory chips (they are sealed).

Answer (score 0):

Water is a bad way to do this. If you just use water, salt it heavily and the let it corrode when you remove it from the water and let the atmosphere / drying cycle corrode the contacts. Physical destruction of the memory and logic board and storage is far better. That way you don’t risk fire or lithium battery damage from a short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome question.  Curiously, did you set the hostname of the device to Rasputin! ?....  If so, this will prevent it from drowning and short circuiting, as your 22 hours submerged in water does attest.

Next, where drowning failed, poison, stabbing, pistol shots and then rolling the tenacious mac mini in a swath of rug and jetisonning it into a river might work...  My colleagues are correct in relating the power of the hammer to F*CK SH*T up real well, so you might want to whack it a few on the way to the river.

If this fails, you have only one recourse: thermite.  If that fails, run for the woods, and hide, cause you are F*CKED.

F.